# How to use Java to install multiple apks into android device

Tags: java, android, automation, installation, apk

I have multiple app apks downloaded into my laptop. I want to use java to write a script, so that all apks can be installed to my device automatically. Anybody can help me out with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are Using Linux

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /dir/*
do
  adb install $file 
done
```

you can install using adb like

```
adb install application1.apk & adb install application2.apk & adb install applicaiton3
```

you can install using

```
for %f in (D:\Directory\*.apk) do adb install "%f"
```

using MAC

```
for file in apk/*; 
do 
./adb install $file; 
done
```

and a final solution using batch file created By Osman Vielma

```
@echo Preparing to install all .apk files in "C:\Directory\" folder to device

@pause

@for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b "C:\Directory\"*.apk') do @"C:\Directory_ADB\ADB\adb.exe" install -r "C:\Directory\%%f"

@echo End of Batch File

@pause
```